# How do i compare a variable to another e.g i want to if (var1 > var2 by 1) then do this c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to compare two variables to see the first variable is greater than the second variable by a certain number, and if it is I want it to do something specific. In C++.

```
int enterPieces, numberOfPeople, piecesLeft;
    static const unsigned values_group_1 = (1 << 1);
    cin >> enterPieces >> numberOfPeople;
    if (enterPieces<0 || enterPieces > 1000 || numberOfPeople < 0 || numberOfPeople >
        1000 || enterPieces == numberOfPeople)
        exit(0);
    piecesLeft = numberOfPeople-enterPieces;
    if (piecesLeft == 1)
        cout << "Dr. Chaz will have " << piecesLeft << " piece of chicken left over!" << endl;
    else if (piecesLeft << values_group_1){
        piecesLeft=abs(piecesLeft);
```

Comment: You need to show (in an MCVE) what you tried.  I hope it will help explain your goal, because  I interpret your prose differently than Remy's answer(s).

Comment: You mean `if (var > var2 + 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the two variables to get the difference between them, eg:

```
if ((var1 > var2) &&      // is the 1st var greater?
    ((var1 - var2) >= N)) // if so, greater by N or more?
{
    // do something...
}
```

Alternatively, you could omit the first check, since the result of the subtraction will not satisfy `>= N` if the 1st variable is less than or equal to the 2nd variable (assuming signed types are used, or you can guarantee that the result will never be `< 0`):

```
if ((var1 - var2) >= N)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: interesting, thanks for the fast reply! i will try that.